# Measure Theory "Magical" Unions and Intersections

Tags: measure-theory

In reading Knapp's Basic Real Analysis, in chapter 5 section 2, I came across something which I just cannot understand.  If $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions, then he says that $$(f+g)^{-1}(c,+\infty)=\bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}}f^{-1}(c+r,+\infty]\cap g^{-1}(-r,+\infty].$$  I spent a lot of time thinking and working with how he derived this, or even how the conclusion holds, but I cannot.  So, if someone could help me figure out exactly how this is true, and how this "magical" equation was derived, then I would be very appreciative.

Comment: You should say $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Does this help?

Comment: That was just a typo, but it still doesn't address my lack of understanding unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in(f+g)^{-1}\big[(c,\to)\big]$; then $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)>c$. Let $s=f(x)-c$; $f(x)=c+s$, and therefore $g(x)>-s$. We’d like to find a rational $r$ such that $f(x)>c+r$ and $g(x)>-r$, since we would then have $$x\in f^{-1}\big[(c+r,\to)\big]\cap g^{-1}\big[(-r,\to)\big]\;.\tag{1}$$ Since $f(x)=c+s$, this implies that we want $c+s>c+r$, or $r<s$. We also need to have $g(x)>-r$. In short, we need a rational number $r$ such that $-s<-r<g(x)$, and since $-s<g(x)$ and the rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$, there must be one.

We’ve now shown that for each $x\in(f+g)^{-1}\big[(c,\to)\big]$ there is an $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $(1)$ holds, and it follows at once that

$$(f+g)^{-1}\big[(c,\to)\big]\subseteq\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb Q}\left(f^{-1}\big[(c+r,\to)\big]\cup g^{-1}\big[(-r,\to)\big]\right)\;.$$

The opposite inclusion is easier. If

$$x\in\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb Q}\left(f^{-1}\big[(c+r,\to)\big]\cup g^{-1}\big[(-r,\to)\big]\right)\;,$$, there is an $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $(1)$ holds. It follows that $f(x)>c+r$ and $g(x)>-r$ and hence that $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)>c+r-r=c$, i.e., that $x\in(f+g)^{-1}\big[(c,\to)\big]$.

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you.

Comment: @Jebruho: You’re welcome (and thank *you*).

Answer (score 4):

It might help to consider the following equivalent statement: for any $x$, we have $f(x) +g(x) > c$ iff there exists $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) > c+r$ and $g(x) > -r$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(x) + g(x) < c$. Then since $f(x) < c - g(x)$, you can choose a rational number so that $f(x) < r < c - g(x)$.  You have $x\in[f < r]$.  Now $c - g(x) > r$, so
$g(x) < c - r$; therefore $x \in [g < c - r]$. We have just shown that 
$$[f + g < c] = \bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q} }[f < r]\cap [ g < c - r].$$

The reverse inequality is easier.